# print all terminals of a user except current

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to print all terminals of a user except the current terminal used for doing this check. To fetch the current terminal I am using `tty` command , which works fine if used alone. However when coupled with `awk` , its failing.

Why below command fail?

```
 -->ls -l /dev/pts/  |grep ${USER} |awk -v current_tty=$(tty) '{n=split(current_tty,a,"/")} $0 !~ a[n] {print $0}'
awk: fatal: cannot open file `tty' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

However when I replace `$(tty)` with `$(echo /dev/pts/44)` then same command worked.

```
 -->tty
/dev/pts/44

 -->ls -l /dev/pts/  |grep ${USER} |awk -v current_tty=$(echo /dev/pts/44) '{n=split(current_tty,a,"/")} $0 !~ a[n] {print $0}' 
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 15 Feb  5 10:16 15
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 19 Feb  5 10:16 19
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 28 Feb  5 10:16 28
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 35 Feb  5 10:22 35
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 39 Feb  5 10:18 39
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 43 Feb  5 10:18 43
crw------- 1 monk tty  136, 46 Feb  5 10:16 46
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136, 48 Feb  5 10:16 48
crw--w---- 1 monk tty  136,  8 Feb  5 10:16 8
```

I ran `$(tty)` alone, its working

```
 -->echo $(tty)
/dev/pts/44
```

Alternate approach tried which resulted in same result:

```
ps -eaf |awk -v USER=${USER} -v current_terminal=$(tty) '$1==USER && $6 != "?"'
```

Comment: IMHO experts don't advise to parse `ls` output.

Comment: I knew this would come, I tried with `ps -eaf |awk -v USER=${USER} -v current_terminal=$(tty) '$1==USER && $6 != "?"'` to avoid `ls` usage. Still same issue.

Comment: @monk , use `ps -eaf` and `grep` for `pid`

Comment: @P.... can you tell how

Comment: try `ps -eaf |awk -v user=${USER} -v term_pid=$$ '$1==user && $2 != term_pid && $6 != "?"'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find /dev/pts -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
    -type c \
    -user "$USER" \
  ! -path "$(tty)" \
    -print
```

That is to say, we're finding:

- Direct children of `/dev/pts`
- ...which are character devices (like all PTYs should be)...
- ...and which are owned by the current user...
- ...and which are *not* the current tty.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I am super confused why `$(tty)` with `awk` does not went well. Any clue ?

Comment: Nope. Not interested in teasing apart what the buggy awk code does.

Comment: thanks, If you don't know . I better stop chasing the RCA for this :)

Comment: For this to work on OSX, I had to use: `find /dev -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1     -type c     -user "$USER"   ! -path "$(tty)"`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
ps -eaf |\
awk -v user=${USER} -v term_pid=$$ '$1==user && $3 != term_pid && $2!=term_pid && $6 != "?"'
```

***Explanation of above code:*** I have used shell's `$$` facility to take current session's id, then in `awk` conditions I am checking for 2nd and 3rd fields both shouldn't be equal to `$$` value too. By putting 2nd and 3rd both fields condition it will remove child ids of current shell too.